# Is the tunnelling effect already naturally accounted for in the density functional theory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, many-body, quantum-tunneling, density-functional-theory

Would it be correct to say the [tunnelling effect](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_tunnelling) is already naturally accounted for in the [density functional theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_functional_theory) or the [Hartree-Fock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartree%E2%80%93Fock_method) formulation of the many-body problem to the Shrodinger equation?

The reason I ask about it is that I came upon some articles, on chemistry e.g. [this](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/jacs.7b06035) and [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.04303) and biology e.g. [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3768233/), that seem to take quantum tunnelling which is concomitant to quantum mechanics as a new mechanism that is unaccounted for before. I wonder it is the case for the part of chemistry, such as the density functional theory and molecular orbital theory that are fundamentally built on quantum mechanics.

Comment: Could you please add a bit more motivation for your question. Tunnelling is just a general phenomenon in QM. Why should we account for it?

Comment: @NDewolf: I have edited my question to address your question.

Comment: Quantum tunneling is when a wave function passes through a barrier and not over it. The Arhenius rate equation has a barrier of Ea where Ea is the activation energy and determines the rate of reaction. In a battery we catalyze the reaction through quantum tunneling(ie a battery discharges 1000s of times faster than simply the reaction between 2 electrodes)

Comment: @ChemEng: 1) What does Arrhenius equation have to do with quantum tunneling? 2) Are you trying to tell me what quantum tunneling is? Neither of these issues answers my question.

Comment: @Hans ya I just thought I'd add it as it is not on Wikipedia. Catalysis in a battery is a form on quantum tunneling as are some other forms of catalysis

Comment: @ChemEng: Of course, catalysis involves quantum tunneling. Appreciate that. I am interested in answering my original question though.